# Why does gamlss give incorrect estimates of ex-gaussian distribution parameters?

Tags: r, estimation, gamlss

From the *gamlss.dist* page for `exGAUSS`:

> The ex-Gaussian distribution is often used by psychologists to model response time (RT). It is defined by adding two random variables, one from a normal distribution and the other from an exponential. The parameters `mu` and `sigma` are the mean and standard deviation from the normal distribution variable while the parameter `nu` is the mean of the exponential variable.

Here is how we're supposed to estimate the parameters:

```
library(gamlss)
y <- rexGAUS(100, mu = 300, nu = 100, sigma = 35)
m1 <- gamlss(y ~ 1, family = exGAUS)
m1
```

Unfortunately the estimates are way off:

```
Family:  c("exGAUS", "ex-Gaussian") 
Fitting method: RS() 

Call:  gamlss(formula = y ~ 1, family = exGAUS) 

Mu Coefficients:
(Intercept)  
      302.9  
Sigma Coefficients:
(Intercept)  
      3.496  
Nu Coefficients:
(Intercept)  
       4.63
```

A package that has disappeared from CRAN, *retimes*, can still be installed from

```
https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/retimes/retimes_0.1-2.tar.gz
```

It has a function `mexgauss`:

```
library(retimes)
mexgauss(y)
```

gives:

```
       mu     sigma       tau 
319.42880  55.51562  85.94403
```

which is closer.

Comment: Are you asking a question here? Stack Overflow is a question and and answer site. It's not a place to post information. Perhaps you can edit your post to make it clear what your question is.

Comment: Note that a log link is used for sigma and nu by default, which I think could make the output a little confusing for those two parameters since output appears to be on the model (log) scale.

Comment: @aosmith: your insight is obviously the solution that I should have seen. We know that nu = 100, log(100) = 4.605, which is close enough to the estimate of 4.63. Likewise log(sigma) = log(35) = 3.555, which close to the estimate of 3.496. The output of gamlss is indeed confusing, and could be made more explict.

Comment: @MrFlick: I assumed that a grammatically-defined question in the subject of an SE question would be sufficient. Please let me know if a grammatically-defined question is also required in the body of an SE question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The estimates for `sigma` and `nu` do appear to be way off in the model output. This is because `exGaus()` uses a log link for both those parameters by default. From the documentation, showing the defaults:

> exGAUS(mu.link = "identity", sigma.link = "log", nu.link = "log")

The output shows results on the model scale so the estimates for those two parameters are given on the log scale.

If we exponentiate the results for `sigma` and `nu` then we get estimates that look more reasonable and much closer to what we'd expect.

```
# estimated sigma should be close to 35
exp(3.496)
#> [1] 32.98325

# estimated nu shoud be close to 100
exp(4.63)
#> [1] 102.5141
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>